# Absolutely positioned tooltip (in :before) cut off by header bar

Tags: css, tooltip, pseudo-element, absolute

I have a Header Div that is at the top of the page and a sibling div that is the main content of the page.
In there there is a tooltip that when positioned too close to the header gets cut off by it. 
HTML for tooltip:

```
<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="List of rules to use for automated email marketing integration with MailChimp">
  <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
</span>
```

CSS for tooltip:

```
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: none;
}
[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: fade-out($light-black, .1);
  color: $white;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

the tooltip is the :before of the span
CSS for header:

```
.main-header {
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: #9CBB71;
}
```

what it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjWWi.png)
the very weird thing is that if i make the header opacity:0, or background-color: transparent, it looks like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lHG9.png)

Comment: is the header or main positioned and  do they have a z-index?  If so the only way to get the tooltip on top of the header is for the main to have a higher z-index than the header

Comment: should've mentioned this,  z-index doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: probably not if you are applying it to the tooltip, please answer the above question in my comment or create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem as with the current information it is impossible to say what is causing your issue

Comment: neither are positioned nor have z-indexs